# How can I save the 'previous' and 'next' iteration of an object in a loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, iteration

I am working on a program that grabs a number before, and after an incidence of a string and then compares those numbers - but it can only happen if the incidence of that string is there.

I've tried iterating through the object.keys (maybe I didn't understand how correctly)

I've tried nesting loops (which logged individual letters in the string 'restart')

```
let formattedTemps = [ 10,'restart',68,80,'restart',70.1,'restart',
  72,80,'restart',69,'restart',78,'restart',84,100,300,50,'restart',70,
'restart',90,'restart',50,'restart',100 ]

const switch = (Array) => {
  console.log(formattedTemps)
  let previousValue = 0
  let nextValue = 0
  for (let elements of array) {
    console.log(previousValue)
    console.log(nextValue)
    // let previousValue = elements[-1]
    // let nextValue = elements[1]
    //console.log(previousValue , element, nextValue
        // save the iterables beside 'restart' on both sides here
      }
    }
```

My expected results are that I get the value both before and after the string 'restart' logged (because I would then compare them).

What has been happening is a whole bunch of undefined values i.e: multiple lines of undefined, 'restart', undefined(with the commented out code) and multiple 0's with it is as it is now.

Comment: `temperature[-1]` is undefined, you're accessing out of bound of array

Comment: You've said "loop within a loop" but I only see one layer of loop...?

Comment: ahh @T.J.Crowder I tried a loop within a loop earlier but console. logged restart as individual letters with string values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to capture the last index of the iteration in the accumulator (accumulator or `acc` in my code is the first parameter of the `Array.reduce` callback) and only print the `previous` and `next` when the current element is `restart` or any `string`

Here is my attempt to explain the logic behind this:

- In the 1st iteration, nothing is printed as the element is a `number`. We just return the current index as the value of the accumulator.
- In the second iteration, the condition `typeof ele === "string"` is satisfied so now the value of `acc` is `0` (as it holds the last visited index) which would be `previous` and the next is one more than the current index.
- Every time the last visited index of the array iteration is returned as the value of the accumulator (`acc`) which we can use in the current iteration to find the value of the previous element. Then we print if the current element is a string. The value of the next element would reside in one more than the current index `idx` of the array.

```js
let formattedTemps = [ 10,'restart',68,80,'restart',70.1,'restart',
  72,80,'restart',69,'restart',78,'restart',84,100,300,50,'restart',70,
'restart',90,'restart',50,'restart',100 ]

const highLimitSwitch = (formattedTemps) => {
  formattedTemps.reduce((acc, ele, idx, arr) => {
   if(typeof arr[acc] === "number" && typeof ele === "string" && typeof arr[idx + 1] === "number"){
     console.log(`${arr[acc]} ${ele} ${arr[idx + 1]}`)
   }
   return idx;
  }, 0)
}
highLimitSwitch(formattedTemps);
```

Comment: This is a weird way to use reduce

Comment: @JordanS does it feel like a hack? :)

Comment: Feels like a hack. Reduce is already a little iffy as is, but this is pretty wild :)

Comment: Thank you for explaining, I did some study on .map(), .reduce() & .filter() but I am still feeling like I am getting the hang of things - been coding on and off for 2 years but this is the first time It hasn't been part of some tutorial or something in awhile.

Comment: @JasonHarder - This is **dramatically** more complicated than it needs to be, and doesn't do anything to ensure that the operands on either side of `restart` are numbers. All you need (as I demonstrated) is a simple loop.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I added the number checks, Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Loop through using the index instead of using `for of`. Then if an element at that index is `'restart'`, you can go back one index and forward one index to get the values.

```js
let formattedTemps = [ 10,'restart',68,80,'restart',70.1,'restart',
  72,80,'restart',69,'restart',78,'restart',84,100,300,50,'restart',70,
'restart',90,'restart',50,'restart',100 ]

for (let i = 0; i < formattedTemps.length; i++) {
  let temp = formattedTemps[i]
  if (typeof temp === 'string') {
    beforeTemp = formattedTemps[i-1];
    afterTemp = formattedTemps[i+1];
    console.log(beforeTemp, temp, afterTemp);
  }
}
```

Comment: You can add checks for first and last index mate.

Comment: This assumes well formatted data, but you are right.

Answer (score 1):

You can access beyond either side of the array, which will give you the value `undefined`. So you can just check to see if you have a number either side of a string:

```
const highLimitSwitch = (formattedTemps) => {
  for (const [index, operation] of formattedTemps.entries()) {
      const num1 = formattedTemps[index - 1];
      const num2 = formattedTemps[index + 1];
      if (typeof num1 === "number" && typeof operation === "string" && typeof num2 === "number") {
          console.log(num1, operation, num2);
      }
  }
};
```

Live Exmaple:

```js
let formattedTemps = [10,'restart',68,80,'restart',70.1,'restart',
  72,80,'restart',69,'restart',78,'restart',84,100,300,50,'restart',70,
'restart',90,'restart',50,'restart',100 ];

const highLimitSwitch = (formattedTemps) => {
  for (const [index, operation] of formattedTemps.entries()) {
      const num1 = formattedTemps[index - 1];
      const num2 = formattedTemps[index + 1];
      if (typeof num1 === "number" && typeof operation === "string" && typeof num2 === "number") {
          console.log(num1, operation, num2);
      }
  }
};

highLimitSwitch(formattedTemps);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

(Notice how `70.1` is used twice, both as `num2` and as `num1` of the next operation, because there is only one number between two `'restart'`s in the sample data.)

---

Or if you can **assume** that when you see a string it has numbers on either side of it (as your [currently-accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55433260/157247) does), then it's even simpler:

```
const highLimitSwitch = (formattedTemps) => {
  for (const [index, operation] of formattedTemps.entries()) {
      if (typeof operation === "string") {
          const num1 = formattedTemps[index - 1];
          const num2 = formattedTemps[index + 1];
          console.log(num1, operation, num2);
      }
  }
};
```

Live Exmaple:

```js
let formattedTemps = [10,'restart',68,80,'restart',70.1,'restart',
  72,80,'restart',69,'restart',78,'restart',84,100,300,50,'restart',70,
'restart',90,'restart',50,'restart',100 ];

const highLimitSwitch = (formattedTemps) => {
  for (const [index, operation] of formattedTemps.entries()) {
      if (typeof operation === "string") {
          const num1 = formattedTemps[index - 1];
          const num2 = formattedTemps[index + 1];
          console.log(num1, operation, num2);
      }
  }
};

highLimitSwitch(formattedTemps);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: That's fine - for my purposes, the same number can be compared multiple times.

Now for me to study and learn from the implimentation! (thanks!)

Comment: `const highLimitSwitch = (formattedTemps) => {
  for (const [index, operation] of formattedTemps.entries()) {`
**//since .enteries can be broken down as key value pairs - we are telling javascript the 1st is an index and the 2nd is a defined datatype **
      `const num1 = formattedTemps[index - 1]; 
      const num2 = formattedTemps[index + 1];`
**square brackets are letting javascript know num1 and 2 are iterations**

Comment: `if (typeof num1 === "number" && typeof operation === "string" && typeof num2 === "number") {
          console.log(num1, operation, num2);
      }
  }
};` 

typeOf arguments must be strings.

Comment: @JasonHarder - No, `typeof` operands do not need to be strings. There'd be no point to `typeof` if that were the case. Try this in your console: `const a = 42; console.log(typeof a);` `typeof`'s **result** is always a string, but its operand can be anything. The checks in the answer are correct.

Comment: Well I mean to say if you're looking for number the typeOf argument would be 'number' which is a string - so I either misunderstood or miscommunicated

Comment: @JasonHarder - I'm afraid I don't follow you there at all. The typeof checks in the answer are correct. The operands are the entries from the array, which are either numbers or strings, the result from `typeof` is always a string (`"number"` or `"string"`), and that's what the code in the answer compares them to.

Comment: I see I miswrote! what I should have said is that the results are strings that we use as arguments when we define what we look for. 

I feel like I was not fully understanding at that time. the input, in this case, being the array itself and the output is a string representing the datatype.

Answer (score 1):

You could map new arrays if the actual value is a string. Then filter and keep the arrays.

```js
var array = [10, 'restart', 68, 80, 'restart', 70.1, 'restart', 72, 80, 'restart', 69, 'restart', 78, 'restart', 84, 100, 300, 50, 'restart', 70, 'restart', 90, 'restart', 50, 'restart', 100],
    result = array
        .map((v, i, a) => typeof v === 'string' && [a[i - 1], v, a[i + 1]])
        .filter(Boolean);

console.log(result.map(a => a.join(' ')));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```